# Предсказание временного ряда с помощью lstm

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras, временные-ряды

Я начал изучение изучение библиотеки `keras` для того, чтобы предсказывать временные ряды (в особенности с помощью lstm).

В качестве туториала я выбрал статью Джейсона Броунли (https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/). По ней у меня есть пару вопросов.

В начале параграфа *LSTM Data Preparation* появляется от части непонятный для меня механизм действий.

*Transform Time Series to Supervised Learning* - предполагает, что мы переходим к машинному обучению с учителем, что логично. Но делается это следующим образом:

```
def timeseries_to_supervised(data, lag=1):
    df = DataFrame(data)
    columns = [df.shift(i) for i in range(1, lag+1)]
    columns.append(df)
    df = concat(columns, axis=1)
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return df



   0           0
0    0.000000  266.000000
1  266.000000  145.899994
2  145.899994  183.100006
3  183.100006  119.300003
4  119.300003  180.300003
```

То есть наш временной ряд разбивается на Х и y. Где в качестве Х у нас значения временного ряда, только сдвинутые на один шаг вперед, а самое первое значение, которое становится Nan, мы перевоплощаем в 0. В качестве y выступают обычные (не сдвинутые) значения нашего временного ряда

**1 вопрос:** В статье не указывается, почему именно этим образом мы формируем Х и y. Почему не легче использовать даты или индексы наших данных? Почему именно этот способ используется (не только в этой статье) для формирования обучения с учителем?

Ну и собственно **2 вопрос**, вытекающий из первого:
В главе *Complete LSTM Example* используется функция для предсказания:

```
# make a one-step forecast
def forecast_lstm(model, batch_size, X):
    X = X.reshape(1, 1, len(X))
    yhat = model.predict(X, batch_size=batch_size)
    return yhat[0,0]
```

И еще полный цикл предсказания с используемой функцией выше

```
# walk-forward validation on the test data
predictions = list()
for i in range(len(test_scaled)):
    # make one-step forecast
    X, y = test_scaled[i, 0:-1], test_scaled[i, -1]
    yhat = forecast_lstm(lstm_model, 1, X)
    # invert scaling
    yhat = invert_scale(scaler, X, yhat)
    # invert differencing
    yhat = inverse_difference(raw_values, yhat, len(test_scaled)+1-i)
    # store forecast
    predictions.append(yhat)
    expected = raw_values[len(train) + i + 1]
    print('Month=%d, Predicted=%f, Expected=%f' % (i+1, yhat, expected))
```

Как так получается, что модель предсказывает по сдвинутым значениям ряда? Буду очень благодарен за объяснение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кажется, вы не совсем понимаете в чём смысл таких моделей. А смысл именно в том, что **по нескольким предыдущим значениям** предсказывается **следующее значение**. И не важно какая у этих значений дата, индекс или что. Из данных есть только N предыдущих значений, такая вот модель. В этом суть моделей типа `RNN`, `LSTM` и прочих подобных. В принципе, на этом же основаны модели предсказания временных рядов семейства `ARIMA` (хотя я в них не силён и могу тут ошибаться). Да - такие модели не учитывают сезонность и прочие факторы, которые можно было бы извлечь из даты, поэтому в реальной жизни их используют в основном для кратковременных предсказаний. Ну, либо сначала вычитают из данных сезонный фактор, тренд и т.п., а потом уже применяют такие модели.

1. Почему такой способ? Потому что это удобно. Например, вы берёте 5 предыдущих значений и по ним вычисляете текущее значение. У вас получается обычная табличка с данными, вы можете применять любые модели, которые работают с **табличными данными**, начиная с линейной регрессии и заканчивая ансамблями (например, `XGBoost`). Модели, которые работают именно с временными рядами специфичные - их меньше, с ними нужно уметь обращаться, проверять их работу нужно особо тщательно. А тут у вас обычные табличные данные и обычные модели, с которыми все умеют работать, которые легко настраивать, интерпретировать. Удобно.
2. Почему делаются такие преобразования данных (дифференцирование, скалирование)? И теория и практика показывают, что при таком варианте работы с данными (предсказание по сдвинутым данным) лучше получается предсказывать **изменение** данных, чем их абсолютную величину. Да это и в целом касается предсказания следующего значения в задаче на временные ряды. Поэтому и берётся разница между соседними значениями, а не сами значения. Ну и ещё нормализация значений делается.

P.S. По итогам обсуждения в комментариях должен напомнить известный факт. Обычно **лучшее предсказание следующего шага** временного ряда, будь это курс акций или что-то ещё более-менее непрерывное - это просто **предыдущее значение ряда**. У вас может получиться прекрасная метрика на вашем предсказании, но не обманывайтесь, а сравните, какой скор получит модель, которая предсказывает следующее значение равное предыдущему. Не исключено, что такая модель даст скор лучше, чем ваша более сложная модель.

А если вы попытаетесь предсказывать не следующий шаг ряда, а сразу через несколько шагов вперёд, то обнаружите, что с каждым таким шагом прогноз всё больше расходится с реальностью и сделать с этим по большому счёту почти ничего нельзя. Неопределённость неизбежно нарастает, поскольку обычно предсказываете вы всё-таки довольно случайный процесс.

Comment: Да, вы правы. До меня сейчас только дошел принцип работы. Про дифференцирование и скалирование я понимаю. Просто, насколько я понял, в статье мы берем только 1 предыдущее значение и по нему предсказываем (поправьте, пожалуйста, если я не прав). У меня просто недопонимание, как модель может лишь по одному значению давать такой крутой результат. Я применил этот алгоритм на своих данных (к скалированию и дифф. я добавил еще фильтр) и получил практически безошибочный предикт. Меня это очень смущает.

Comment: Я попробовал предсказать и трейн (ради интереса) и тест. То есть каждый раз вкладывал Х для того и для другого в функцию форкаста. То есть, по сути, модель каждый раз опирается на последнее значение(я) нашей трейн выборки? И, от части, вложив в функцию предикта трейн (к примеру, взять такое же кол-во данных от трейна, что и у теста) и тест,я должен получить одинаковый результат, но на практике результаты разные. Почему так?

Comment: я достаточно сложно объясняю, надеюсь вы поймете о чем я)

Comment: @hiddenlayer А сами предсказания вы смотрели? Насколько я помню, лучшее предсказание - это тупо предыдущее значение ряда ))  Не исключено, что модель предсказывает нулевое изменение. Сдвига 1, конечно, мало по-хорошему. Обычно берётся больше значений. А если взять `LSTM`, то ей можно скармливать довольно большие цепочки и она сама выберет, какие сдвиги полезны. Так что `LSTM` теретически может и сезонность учесть, если сочтёт полезными значения, скажем, за год назад.

Comment: @hiddenlayer Насчёт трейна и теста я вас честно говоря не понял, вы правы. Но это нормально ))  А так вообще когда вы получаете "безошибочный предикт" я бы всё-таки хотел знать, как вы его оцениваете. И да, одно дело делать предсказания на один шаг вперёд - тут скорее всего просто будет значение, близкое к предыдущему шагу и никакой магии. А вы попробуйте предсказать значение не на шаг вперёд, а подальше. И вот тут вас будет поджидать весьма неприятный сюрприз :)

Comment: Я использую данные, в которых частота - 15 минут ( то есть на один день - 96 измерений). У меня этих данных на несколько месяцев. То есть значений очень много. Я в трейн пихаю все данные, за исключением последнего дня. И предсказываю на 96 значений вперед (то есть какие значения будут на этот день). NRMSE где-то 0.1, где-то 0.02 (просто у меня много рядов и они примерно все одинаковые с той же сезонностью). И меня такой результат пугает))

Comment: у меня уже параноя касательно того "а вдруг это не предсказания, а вдруг эти значения попали в трейн", хотя по коду все нормально, я следовал статье.

Comment: @hiddenlayer Ну, надо смотреть данные, я так абстрактно не могу. Главное проверьте, что этот день, который вы предсказываете, никуда не утёк )  А по-хорошему это нужно не на одном дне проверять, а на нескольких. Грубо говоря, сначала отрезаете последнюю неделю, учитесь на этом, предсказываете следующий день, смотрите скор. Дальше отрезаете 6 дней от данных, опять предсказываете, смотрите скор. И т.д. А дальше уже смотрите не один скор, а эти вот все 7 насколько они хороши. А то вдруг ваш последний день особый (или наоборот слишком типичный) и только на нём хороший скор получился.

Comment: Если разрешите, я задам последний вопрос. Точнее разъясню про свой "эксперемент". Вы сказали "не важно какая у этих значений дата, индекс или что". Я обучил данные на трейн выборке. У меня есть тест (а именно его Х), состоящий из 96 значений, а также я решил взять трейн (по которому обучал) и "отодрать" из него  96 первых значений 9 (индексов) и закинуть в предикт. Получилось, что результаты отличаются из чего я сделал вывод, что эти "проклятые" Х на что-то влияют. Хотя по моей логике результат должен был получится один и тот же. Поправьте меня,пожалуйста, если я где-то не прав.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128928/discussion-between-crazyelf-and-hidden-layer).